# How do I include a multi-module project in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

I'm trying to add a feature into a multi-module Gradle Java project (it's spring-integration if you're curious). I've forked the project onto my local machine and am creating a separate Gradle project that references this locally cloned project for development.

In my new project the settings.gradle file looks like this:

```
include ":springint"
project(":springint").projectDir = file("/users/me/git/spring-integration")

rootProject.name = 'sprinttest'
```

and I reference it from my build.gradle with:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":springint")
...
```

The problem is that it seems to only consider the build.gradle of that /git/spring-integration directory and not its settings.gradle. That's an issue because there quite a few submodules that are referenced via its settings.gradle file that don't get picked up when I run my local project. The error I get is:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating project ':springint'.
>     Project with path 'spring-integration-test-support' could not be found in project ':springint'.

If you look at spring-integration's `settings.gradle` you see that it includes all these subprojects dynamically:

```
rootProject.name = 'spring-integration'

rootDir.eachDir { dir ->
    if (dir.name.startsWith('spring-integration-')) {
        include ":${dir.name}"
    }
}
```

I would think that gradle would automatically incorporate the settings.gradle of this dependency at build time but it's not, as this is why, for example, **spring-integrationtest-support** is not found. Am I missing something, or should I "recreate" the same logic from this project's settings into my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only define one and only one `settings.gradle` file.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:defining_a_multiproject_build

> To define a multi-project build, you need to create a settings file.
>   The settings file lives in **the root directory of the source tree**, and
>   specifies which projects to include in the build

If you want to include a subproject within a subproject, use this syntax :

```
include "a-subproject:an-inner-subproject"
```

It can look like that :

```
include "springint"
project(":springint").projectDir = file("/users/me/git/spring-integration")

rootProject.name = 'sprinttest'

project(":springint").projectDir.eachDir { dir ->
    if (dir.name.startsWith('spring-integration-')) {
        include "springint:${dir.name}"
    }
}
```